# Split 1 large C++ classes into multiple classes, whilst still using original classes member syntax

Tags: c++, refactoring, wrapper, arduino-c++

So I'm currently working on a project refactoring an Arduino library, using the vs plugin vMicro.

The library itself had various large groups of methods like "`NXG_Rover_Sounds`" and "`NXG_Rover_MotorCtrl`" which I've decided to separate into there own classes, all with the appropriate #includes, friending, class method refrences and static...izing.

The code itself looks nice and compiles fine, but my boss wants to be able to call all the methods by their original (or at least just one) syntax, like they were all members of the same class back when they were in "`NXG_Rover`".

Like if I created an object `rover`, to use `rover.playSound()`, instead of `NXG_Sound::playSound()`

He threw around the term "Wrapper class", or "Wrapper Functions".
So I did a bit of digging, and the best documentation I could find, I'm kinda struggling to wrap my head around: https://stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf

Can anyone out there explain how it would work / the appropriate syntax involved?
Is there an easier option?

Comment: You've removed a function while refactoring. Add it back and let it call your refactored function. So users don't get bothered by your refactor. That is, wrapped your refactored function into original function. If you want more explanation, make a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Dam... now that you mention it, its kinda obvious.
Here I am, thinking I need some kind of crazy new syntax or library.
So at this stage I'm gonna build constructors for each new subsequent class and call the new classes functions via an object inside of the original classes cpp func def.

Thanks @Louis Go